# Make recompiles non-updated files

Tags: makefile

I was experimenting with GNU make. Suppose, I have 3 C files with the following structure:

```
hellomake.c
    |
    |---------------------
    |                    |
    V                    V
hellofunc.c         hellomake.h
```

makefile:

```
hellomake: hellomake.c hellofunc.c
    gcc -o hellomake hellomake.c hellofunc.c -I.
```

When I type make for the 1-st time, it creates a program `hellomake`. When I run it for the 2-nd time, it prints:

```
make: `hellomake' is up to date.
```

Everything is working correctly.

I tried to use make for compiling LaTeX files. Suppose, I have 2 TeX files:

```
  1.tex
    |
    V
1_data.tex
```

1_data is included into 1.tex internally.

Makefile:

```
COMMAND = pdflatex

all: 1.tex 1_data.tex
    $(COMMAND) 1.tex
```

But it recompiles 1.tex every time I type `make`. Even if none of the files were modified.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make`simply looks at whether or not `all` exists.  Since it doesn't, it attempts to create it (but doesn't even notice that your commands do not create the file!)

Assuming `pdflatex` really creates a file somewhere, use the file name as the target name.  Then it will be recreated only if it is older than the dependencies.

To recapitulate, a Makefile declares a mapping of target files, their dependencies, and how to create them from the dependencies. When a target is missing or out of date with respect to its dependencies, Make runs the commands for recreating it.

(My first attempt at articulating this answer mentioned `.PHONY:` targets as an aside, but that's not really useful in this context; if you declared `.PHONY: all` it would run the recipe even if a file named `all` existed, so that's the opposite behavior of what you are looking for.)

Comment: I got it. I used this: `1.pdf: 1.tex 1_data.tex` instead. And now it works.